# Beginner help: Parsing in C

Tags: c, parsing

I'm relatively new to this concept for parsing. And here is a simple, yet for me, it's mindbreaking, example.

I have a text file containing a series of numbers and letters. In each line of the text there are three elements. a letter, another letter, and a number. Consider the first as the source, the second as the destination and the number as size. The read them and put them into a structure array and be able to arrange them according to size. "a, b, 1" for the first line. "q, s, 5" for the 2nd, etc. And lastly, printing them in an arranged format (which is according to size)

Mind giving me a clues or starting points? 
Update:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
FILE *fp;
fp= fopen("file.txt", "O");
int i;
struct arrangement{
       char source;
       char dest;
       int cost;
       };
struct arrangement rng[22];

for(i=0; i<22 ; i++){
         fscanf(fp, "%c, %c, %d", rng[i].source, rng[i].dest, rng[i].cost);
         printf("%c, %c, %d", rng[i].source, rng[i].dest, rng[i].cost);
}

getch();
return 0;
```

}

will this be able to "store all elements in the array?I still don't have any idea how I will arrange these according to size/cost without the source and destination being left out.

Comment: If it's literally this simple, you could simply use fscanf until EOF

Comment: Why not just show some same data from the file, show what data you are trying to get as a result, and what code you've written so far.

Comment: Stackoverflow works best when questions have a single, specific answer. What have you tried already? What problems did you come across?

Comment: here's part of the text:
a, b, 1
s, g, 5
q, k, 9
o, n, 6
three elements in each line. I should be able to store them in a structure array, arrrange them according to size(descending) then print. I honestly don't know where to start, or how... sorry

Comment: Something like `struct { char c[2], int i;} ar[4], while (fscanf(" %c , %c ,%d", &ar[i].c[0], &ar[i].c[0], &ar[i].i) ==3) i++; qsort(ar, 4, sizeof *ar, fcmp);`  Show more of what you have done to see more help.

Comment: @LeviAckerman You just answered part of Jonathan's question, what about the code you have written so far ? Did you get a chance to check on using fopen and fscan ? Search SO on how to read text files and store them. That is ur starting point.

Comment: this simply prints them, still without arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

fscanf requires pointers to the variables, not the variables themselves. Your code may result in strange results, depending on compiler (gcc may emit a warning/error) and platform.
You also should break the loop if reaching EOF. i may then provide the last used entry (which may be partially valid or not, depending on the input).

Comment: so I need to put '&' or addresses to the variables?

Comment: Yes, you have to apply the address-operator to the variables: pass the address of the variables, not the values (not clear what you mean with "or addresses"). Please read the other anwsers, too,; I did not check other aspects of your code. C is not my focus language fo this kind of task.